# Who knows the Flash IDE : "Burrito" download address? And how to import old version project use Flash builder4.5?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

1,It is the pre-release ,i can't find it now.
2,I can download the Flash Builder 4.5 but i want to know how to import the Burrito's project?
   and which lib or Flex Build Path must i add?
  When i import the Burrito version projects use Flash Builder 4.5 , it says 
   "it can't find the 1017: The definition of base class MobileItemRenderer was not found.  ItemRendererBase.as"

```
    import spark.components.Image;
import spark.components.MobileItemRenderer;
import spark.components.supportClasses.MobileTextField;

public class ItemRendererBase extends MobileItemRenderer
{

    protected var arrowDisplay:Image;

    private var _isShowArrow:Boolean = true;
```

Could not resolve  to a component implementation.  TourDeMobileFlex.mxml   /TourDeMobileFlex/src   line 5  Flex Problem

```
<s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 firstView="views.SampleListView"
                 splashScreenImage="@Embed('icons/tdfsplash.png')">
```

how can resolve it?

3,or who can help me to import the Adobe Sample "TourDeMobileFlex" use Flash Builder 4.5?
   i can't download the (Hero)..........

the adobe says :
"Download the Flash Builder project with all samples from http://flex.org/TourDeMobileFlex.fxp
You must use the preview release of Flash Builder (Hero) to compile the source"

Thanks a lot...

A new flex in android developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your question isn't about IDE but mostly related to the SDK. I can suggest you to use current release version of Flash Builder 4.5 and don't use Flash Builder "Burrito" preview as far as it hasn't release quality.

What about your existent project created in preview version it obviously uses one of the old beats of Flex 4.5 SDK. And the thing you definitely should perform is to migrate your project to the most current release version of Flex 4.5 SDK. If you'll use the most current version of Flash Builder 4.5 (which is 4.5.1 now) it uses that SDK by default.

As far as I can understand you're trying to compile sample [from here](http://flex.org/tour-de-mobile-flex/). The problem is these samples are obsolete now and I strongly recommend you not to rely on them. Try to migrate sample to be compatible with release version of Flex SDK 4.5 or use some other source with Flex mobile apps samples.

If you'll decide to migrate it is very possible [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-1483ec4a12136246e76-8000.html#WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836663fb6012af31eb8a5-8000) will be useful for you. Just replace your `MobileItemRenderer` with [`LabelItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/LabelItemRenderer.html) and I think things will be fine :)

And you can use Flex Mobile Samples [from the new version of Tour de Flex](http://devgirl.org/2011/06/13/new-mobile-samples-in-tour-de-flex/). I think they are the same as in Tour de Mobile Flex but targeted to the release version of Flex SDK.

So finally in short:

- Use the most current release version of Flash Builder.
- Use the most current release version of Flex SDK which is shipped with Flash Builder mentioned above.
- Migrate your Tour de Mobile projects or better use mobile samples from Tour de Flex.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have got it. I have already find some differences of that,just like MobileTextField to StyleableTextField, I am trying to find more differences, and will share it. And I will migrate the codes.
Thank you very very much for your time and share spirit.
We should learn from your spirit...